# in R, pass character vector to dplyr::bid_rows

Tags: r, vector, character, rows, bind

I have this character vector like `n<-"get('mtcars'),get('mtcars')"` but could be 1 to 9 adata different data frames that I want to bind together like `bind_rows(get('mtcars'),get('mtcars'))` but using `bind_rows(n)`.

Comment: I dislike having code as text and using `eval`, but that might be an option. However, to do that, you need to have a valid R expression, and that (after `n<-`) is not valid. Also, vectors are bad for multiple frames, `list` is better suited. For example, `bind_rows(mtcars,mtcars)`, `bind_rows(list(mtcars, mtcars))`, and `do.call(bind_rows, list(mtcars, mtcars))` are all identical.

Comment: Where is this vector coming from? seems like a huge code smell.

Comment: I have a data frame that has colA as an item in a selectInput control in Shiny and colB has the name of the dataframe.  I can get the colA values from the selectInput and get the dataframe name from colB and then build the "get('dfA'), get('dfB')" recognizable by bind_rows?  If there is another way to use selectInput to select different dataframes that have the same structure combine them using bind_rows I would be happy to give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

You can `str_split` the string, and `parse` and `eval` to get the desired result.

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- "get('mtcars'),get('mtcars')"

n %>%
  str_split(",", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  map(~eval(parse(text = .))) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

However, turning strings into evaluated expressions is often not the best approach.